# Difference between push and pushObject in ember js

Tags: javascript, arrays, methods, ember.js, frontend

I am new to ember js. I want to know where to use arr.push() and arr.pushObject() in ember.js.What is the difference between them?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`push` is a vanilla javascript method to add an array entry. `pushObject` works exactly like `push` that adds an entry to the array plus **it will notify the change to Ember** so that the framework will re-render them if used in any dynamic context like a template, computed property etc.,

If you check [this Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/178e9d6c5e1336b3fffb15bab2953ac9?openFiles=controllers.application%5C.js%2C), when you click `push` button, no changes will be reflected in the template. However, if you open the browser console, you can verify that the array has been mutated. This is because the `push` method will add entry but will not tell Ember about the changes hence Ember will not re-render the changes.

However, if you click the `pushObject` button, the array will be mutated as well as the changes will be reflected in the template.

If you want to track the changes you made to the array, it's apt to use `pushObject`.